# Paypal recurring order page not showing amount and initial amount

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

Im having a problem with the amount and adding of initial amount in the order page of paypal SetExpressCheckout.

Currently I have this code:

```
$nvpstr="&AMT=". $paymentAmount;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION=".urlencode("Test Recurring Payment($1 monthly)");
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments";
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
$nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
```

I have this code from here: https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example

I already tried adding the one in the paypal docs but still no luck.
Can someone please advice or show me how can I add the Amount and Initial Amount for this recurring payment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am seeking for the same in java.

Answer (score 0):

The checkout itself and the profile amounts are considered separate things.  You'll need to display the profile details (initial amount, etc.) on your website or application so the customer knows what's going on.

You could go ahead and include service or whatever it is people are signing up for as an item in your SetExpressCheckout request.  This would make it show up and show an amount, but then that really gets ignored unless you end up using DoExpressCheckoutPayment, which you won't normally do when working with subscriptions.

So that would be sort of a work-around that should give you the result you're looking for, but again, I'd just make sure to display those details within your application prior to sending the person over to PayPal.